# How to checkout a private repo using Carthage?

Tags: ios, swift, git, github, carthage

I am trying to checkout a branch from our organization github repo using Carthage but it fails with error message

Cartfile

```
git "ssh://git@github.com:orginaztion/repo.git" "branch"
```

In command line

```
carthage checkout --use-submodules --use-ssh
```

Error message:

```
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git fetch --prune --quiet ssh://git@github.com/orginaztion/repo.git refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* (launched in /var/root/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/repo)) failed with exit code 1
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?